# Restrict IP Address in Window Hosting Envoirment

Tags: vbscript, ip-restrictions

I need a Security Section (Code) to be added to our Web.Config File which sits in a Windows Hosting Environment. This security section is to allow traffic to our web application from all IP addresses except a few ones like; xx.xxx.xx.xx

I have no idea about Visual basic script because i am a php developer, someone can help me to get out of it with script or well guideline

Any suggestion will be appreciative , waiting

Comment: So basically you need some predefined lines of of text appended to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was Able to Add Code to Restrict API in Window Based Hosting , pasting it here for Other People

How it's done

Example IP address restrictions. Comments are enclosed in  and are not required.

Allow all, but block specific IP's or networks

```
<security>
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
<!-- this line allows everybody, except those listed below -->
<clear/>
<!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
<add ipAddress="83.116.19.53"/>
<!-- blocks the specific IP of 83.116.19.53  -->
<add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>
<!--blocks network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->
<add ipAddress="83.116.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>
<!--blocks network 83.116.0.0 to 83.116.255.255-->
<add ipAddress="83.0.0.0" subnetMask="255.0.0.0"/>
<!--blocks entire /8 network of 83.0.0.0 to 83.255.255.255-->
</ipSecurity>
</security>`
```